# Phpbb show custom fields

Tags: php, html, phpbb

I'm trying to show custom profile fields like this in phpbb(3.0.14):

```
<?php if (!defined('IN_PHPBB')) exit; $this->_tpl_include('overall_header.html'); ?>


<h2><?php echo (isset($this->_rootref['PAGE_TITLE'])) ? $this->_rootref['PAGE_TITLE'] : ''; ?></h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo (isset($this->_rootref['S_PROFILE_ACTION'])) ? $this->_rootref['S_PROFILE_ACTION'] : ''; ?>" id="viewprofile">
<div class="panel bg1<?php if ($this->_rootref['S_ONLINE']) {  ?> online<?php } ?>">
    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
    <dl class="left-box details" style="width: 80%;">
        <dd>
        <?php $_custom_fields_count = (isset($this->_tpldata['custom_fields'])) ? sizeof($this->_tpldata['custom_fields']) : 0;
        if ($_custom_fields_count) 
        {
            for ($_custom_fields_i = 0; $_custom_fields_i < $_custom_fields_count; ++$_custom_fields_i)
                    {
                        $_custom_fields_val = &$this->_tpldata['custom_fields'][$_custom_fields_i]; 
                    }?>
                    <dt> <?php echo $_custom_fields_val['PROFILE_FIELD_NAME']; ?>:</dt> 
                    <dd><?php echo $_custom_fields_val['PROFILE_FIELD_VALUE']; ?>
        <?php } ?>          

        </dd>
    </dl>
    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span></div>
</div>

</form>

<?php $this->_tpl_include('jumpbox.html'); $this->_tpl_include('overall_footer.html'); ?>
```

But I see nothing while I've got profile fields? What could be wrong here? Thankyou!